# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity

Tags: hibernate, lucene, sybase, tapestry, hibernate-search

I'm using the following technologies

tapestry 5.4-beta-2

hibernate-core 5.2.5

com.sybase jconn4 7.0.7

hibernate-search 4.2.0.Final

When I attempt to deploy my application, I'm getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
```

Does anybody know what this exception means? I've done numerous searches, but can't seem to find any information on it.

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this.

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect</property>

    <!--DEV Database Connection-->   
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sybase:Tds:domain:5000/test</property>     
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property> 

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>  



@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(
        name = "customanalyzer",
        tokenizer =
        @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),})
@FullTextFilterDefs({
    @FullTextFilterDef(
            name = "managerFilter",
            impl = ManagerFilterFactory.class),
    @FullTextFilterDef(
            name = "employeeFilter",
            impl = EmployeeFilterFactory.class),
    @FullTextFilterDef(
            name = "employeeTimeSheetFilter",
            impl = EmployeeTimeSheetFilterFactory.class),
    @FullTextFilterDef(
            name = "supervisorFilter",
            impl = SupervisorFilterFactory.class),})
public class UserProfile extends StatefulEntity {

    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    @Validate("required")
    @NonVisual
    @Column(
            nullable = false,
            unique = true)
    private String shortname;
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String firstName;
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String lastName;
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String middleInitial;
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String notesName;
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    // 2013.12.03 LDAP allows duplicate email addresses - need to play by the same rules
    @Column(unique = false)
    private String email;
```

Employee

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "employee_profile")
public class EmployeeProfile extends AbstractProfileEntity {

    @NonVisual
    // We could return a DateFormat, but instead we'll return a String which DateField will coerce into a DateFormat.
    private String dateInFormatStr = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    @Validate("required")
    @Column(
            nullable = false,
            unique = true)
    private String empId;
    @NonVisual
    private String author;
```

AbstractProfile

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractProfileEntity extends AbstractAccrualEntity implements TransitoryProfile {

    @NonVisual
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Validate("required")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supervisorId", nullable = false)
    private UserProfile supervisor;
    @NonVisual
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "managerId", nullable = true)
    private UserProfile manager;
    @NonVisual
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String notesName;
```

Full stack trace

```
Feb 04, 2014 2:14:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter app
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'RegistryStartup': Error invoking service contribution method org.domain.test.services.AppModule.initApplication(FullTextSession): java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $Runnable_574fc15253b4.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $Runnable_574fc15253b4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.performRegistryStartup(RegistryImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryWrapper.performRegistryStartup(RegistryWrapper.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:548)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1447)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Error invoking service contribution method org.domain.test.services.AppModule.initApplication(FullTextSession): java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:78)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.addToOrderedConfiguration(RegistryImpl.java:624)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getOrderedConfiguration(RegistryImpl.java:478)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$2.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl$2.invoke(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl.getOrderedConfiguration(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator.getOrderedConfiguration(AbstractServiceCreator.java:123)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator.access$200(AbstractServiceCreator.java:35)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AbstractServiceCreator$1.findResource(AbstractServiceCreator.java:103)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.DelegatingInjectionResources.findResource(DelegatingInjectionResources.java:38)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateInjection(InternalUtils.java:230)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.access$000(InternalUtils.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:288)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$4.invoke(InternalUtils.java:285)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.calculateParameters(InternalUtils.java:292)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$22.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1408)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils$22.invoke(InternalUtils.java:1403)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.InternalUtils.createConstructorConstructionPlan(InternalUtils.java:1400)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.getPlan(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking service contribution method org.domain.test.services.AppModule.initApplication(FullTextSession): java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.invokeMethod(ContributionDefImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.contribute(ContributionDefImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl$9.run(RegistryImpl.java:628)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:55)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.MassIndexerImpl.toRootEntities(MassIndexerImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.MassIndexerImpl.<init>(MassIndexerImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.createIndexer(FullTextSessionImpl.java:209)
    at $FullTextSession_574fc15253bd.createIndexer(Unknown Source)
    at $FullTextSession_574fc15253bc.createIndexer(Unknown Source)
    at org.domain.test.services.AppModule.initApplication(AppModule.java:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.invokeMethod(ContributionDefImpl.java:120)
    ... 104 more
```

Comment: are you sure that you scan your entities before hibernate indexing ?

Comment: I have hit this problem. I put \@Indexed in an abstract base class, problem happens. I add \@Indexed to any derived class, problem gone.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes across this, I was having the same problem today. I know this is late but it could help someone out.

My IDE had auto-imported `org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed` in my model as opposed to `org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed`. Changing the import to the correct thing fixed things straight away.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a reported bug in hibernate search with the massindexer

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1453

The problem I was having was do to one of my entities being annotated with @Indexed however; I was only annotating one of my properties within the entity with @IndexedEmbedded and not annotating any other properties with @Field to be indexed.

Temp work around was to add another property to the index. This is less than ideal, so any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Actually that issue refers to this message being (rightfully) complaining when you didn't declare _any_ entity to be @Indexed. I suspect you're having a different problem.

Comment: @Sanne I still don't understand the problem well enough to report the bug. I can't seem to repeat every time and the exception seems to be to generic to really help me to pin point the issue. I started to think it was a result of the hibernate tables not being fully created before the mass indexer ran. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="hibernate.search.rebuildIndex">false</property>
```

This made my error disappear.